# Java coding conventions: what is the rationale for a space after a cast?

Tags: java, coding-style

I am just wondering if anyone is aware of the ***rationale*** behind this particular item in the standard Java coding conventions. The [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) say to put a space after a cast, like this:

```
Object myObj = (Object) someThing;
                       ^
```

It's the same syntax as casts in C, which never have a space after them:

```
Object myObj = (Object)someThing;
                       ^
```

I thought that this was because the cast is a unary operator. Putting a space there would be like doing this:

```
int x = ++ y;
while (0 < ++ x) { ... }
```

...which is not something you usually see:

```
int x = ++y;
while (0 < ++x) { ... }
```

This seems to be unique to Java, so if anyone has any insight, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `Java` is not `C` so any comparisons are moot, this is like asking why strawberries have their seeds on the outside when all other fruit have them on the inside. equivalency fallacy; Java syntax looks like C so it should be exactly like C which is false.

Comment: ...except that in this case a _person_ made the decision, which implies there was some reason for it. Just curious if there is a reason, or if it was completely arbitrary because "Java is not C".

Comment: The conversation should just end following "_Java coding conventions say to._" unfortunately that's all there is to it.

Comment: Well, it's valid to talk about C in respect to the fact that Java's syntax is HEAVILY based on C's, but, yes, it will just come down to asking whoever wrote the coding conventions, or trying to find some documentation of their rationale from when the decision was made.

Comment: It is probably becuase someone learned to code with an IDE that auto formatted the code in that way. Then they got used to it.

Comment: The assertion "It's the same syntax as casts in C, which never have a space after them" is plain wrong.  C/C++ don't care about spaces, just as Java.  There is nothing wrong with spaces with casts, and actually, for instance, the GNU Coding Standards ask for that space.  Besides "except that in this case a person made the decision" does not make sense either: even the syntax of the language comes from people who made decisions.

Answer (score 4):

Well in [Java Language Specification "Expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) cast expressions do not belong to "15.15 Unary Operators", but have an own subtitle "15.16 Cast Expressions". It is primarly not refered to as cast *operator*, but cast *expression* and the spec says that "the parentheses and the type they contain *are sometimes called* the cast operator."

Comment: That's really interesting. Thanks for that. What's funny is that within that section it's still referred to as a "cast operator".

Answer (score 4):

My personal rationale:

1. In the context of method-call expressions, the argument list binds stronger than a cast, therefore it makes sense to write

   ```
   (foo) method(bar)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   (foo)method(bar)
   ```

   given the syntactical similarity of both sides.

2. There are other contexts where not having a space would arguably look weird:

   ```
   (int)-(a * b)
   ```

   This is actually more relevant in C, where due to typedefs you    may not be able to tell immediately whether the left-hand side is a cast.
3. Casts first and foremost operate on the type of the expression, and on the value only as a side effect of the type conversion, if at all. In that sense casts operate on a higher level than regular unary operators. It therefore seems appropriate to indicate that fact by visually setting them off from the expression they operate on.

Answer (score 3):

The document you link to was written in 1997 and makes the impression of being a document about C coding conventions (for some project or company), translated to Java in a haste. Many of the constructs which are "not recommended" according to the document are actually forbidden by the Java syntax.

There are a few coding conventions which are ubiquitous in Java programs, in particular with respect to the naming of classes and interfaces (`CamelCaseNouns`), methods (`useCamelCaseVerbs`), variables (`camelCaseNouns`) and constants (`CAPITALS`). But other than that, most projects define their own conventions on where to place parentheses and spaces, how much indenting to use, how many empty lines to put between methods, etc. Be consistent within a project, but otherwise use conventions that you (and the other people working on the project) feel most confortable with. If other people do not like your conventions, they can use any of the numerous formatting tools to transform code to their own taste automatically.